# Is it possible to change connection string on cloud service deploy-time?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I wrote an asp.net mvc 4 web site. For my corporation purpose, I created several publish profiles, in order to publish it on differents azure websites. Each profile changes the connection strings.

It worked very well.

I am now trying to do the same thing with an azure cloud service (I added my web site as a web role in a new cloud service project). But I can't find out how to change the connection string of my web role depending of my cloud service project publish profile at deploy-time.

Is there a way to do such a thing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the connection string in the ServiceConfiguration file `.cscfg` of your Role and then use the following in your code to retrieve the setting:

```
string connectionString = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("myConnectionString");
```

You can modify the values in the ServiceConfiguration through the Management Portal once deployed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I already thought about something like this. I wasn't sure this could work, now I know, thanks ^^. But I am looking for an automatic mechanism using publish profile (or something else).

Another solution I thought about was to create a branch for each deployment, with the good configuration, and merge the code regularly.

But I prefer an automatic mechanism if this is possible ^^.

Comment: Have you considered using a web.config transform http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0Wnajs4qJw This will allow you to define multiple web.config sub files that can change the connection string at deployment time.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is exactly what I want. I have to look how it works and if it can be used with Azure. I will let you know !